Running application via Gunicorn gives key error
I am facing a wierd error while running the application via gunicorn.
On the client code I have a key REQUEST_KEY in the header.
One the server code i am trying to read the value by using
req_key = request.headers["REQUEST_KEY"]

This code work all good when I am running with
python main.py

But same when tried with gunicorn configuration given key error for REQUEST_KEY
Command used for gunicorn execution docker
CMD ["gunicorn","--config", "gunicorn_config.py", "main:app"]

and here is my gunicorn configuration file
# File gunicorn_config.py
import os
os.environ['WSGI_ALLOW_UNDERSCORE'] = 'true'
workers = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_PROCESSES', '16'))
threads = int(os.environ.get('GUNICORN_THREADS', '4'))
bind = os.environ.get('GUNICORN_BIND', '0.0.0.0:5001')
forwarded_allow_ips = '*'
secure_scheme_headers = { 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https' }


Error that I get in the server
return unicodify_header_value(self.environ["HTTP" + key])
KeyError: 'HTTP_REQUEST_KEY'
